# I have a tab completion that hangs, is it possible to use strace to find out what is going on?

Tags: autocomplete, debugging, strace

In my example I start typing `sudo su dkay`...`<tab>`... and the command hangs for about a minute before tab completing to `sudo su dkayton`.

I got advised to use strace to find out what is happening.

Any ideas on how to pass the underlying commands of tab completion to strace?

**What I tried:**

I run `top` in one shell to monitor the processes. I then hit tab immediately after `sudo su dkay` in another shell.

Then as quick as I could, I copied the PID of the bash process that resulted to `sudo strace -pXXX -tfo /tmp/strace.log` in a third shell, where XXX is the PID copied.

It still managed to catch more than 2mb of logs. I repeated it twice and was more successful the second time.

I am looking for a more automatic way of completing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Assuming you're using Linux) Use `echo $$` to get the PID of your current shell. Open a new terminal, and run:

```
sudo strace -fp <PID> -o log
```

Switch back to the old shell, try tab completion. Then switch to the new terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to end `strace`. The output will be in the file named `log`. You could also run the `strace` command in the same shell (first authenticating to `sudo` for caching credentials):

```
sudo -v
sudo strace -fp $$ -o log &
```

And then try tab completion. To kill it, `fg`, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

However, if you're using bash, it might be better to try getting verbose debug output from it first:

```
set -o functrace xtrace
PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:$FUNCNAME:$LINENO: '
```

And then try tab completion. You should everything that the completion function executes in the output that follows. For example:

```
bash-5.0$ set -o xtrace functrace
bash-5.0$ PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:${FUNCNAME}:$LINENO: '
+ PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:${FUNCNAME}:$LINENO: '
bash-5.0$ sudo su  /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:_completion_loader:3: local cmd=sudo
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:_completion_loader:5: __load_completion sudo
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:2: dirs=(${BASH_COMPLETION_USER_DIR:-${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/bash-completion}/completions)
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:2: local -a dirs
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:3: local 'OIFS=
' IFS=: dir cmd=sudo compfile
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:2021: for dir in ${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share}
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:5: dirs+=($dir/bash-completion/completions)
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:2021: for dir in ${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share}
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:5: dirs+=($dir/bash-completion/completions)
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:7: IFS='
'
 /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:__load_completion:9: [[ /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion == */* ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for also providing an alternative debugging mechanism. I was able to easily carry out both.